Organising excel file as pandas dataframe
Format of excel file exported from a web app is no in useful.  Need to perform a variety of operations on it to make it suitable as a dataframe.  From bubble.io, excel file would be uploaded by user, manipulated in an amazon s3 bucket using lambda function that removes couple of blank rows at the top (but that I need some cell values from), add columns and moves some columns to become further rows further down the table, before it is pulled back down as a csv file by bubble to add as a new data type (confusing terminology for a table bubble.io uses)
Ultimately, I need to use pandas to convert this excel file...
before
...to this (but as a dataframe I can export as an excel file or csv)
after

Okay, so what have you done so far? Where are you stuck? (Pandas may also be a bad fit for the initial processing; look at using openpyxl directly.)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Once you have the excel file read as a pandas dataframe, you can use stack to get your expected output.
Assuming this dataframe as input:
data = {
    ("01/01/2024", "a"): [1, 2, 3],
    ("01/01/2024", "b"): [4, 5, 6],
    ("01/01/2024", "c"): [7, 8, 9],
    ("02/01/2024", "a"): [10, 11, 12],
    ("02/01/2024", "b"): [13, 14, 15],
    ("02/01/2024", "c"): [16, 17, 18],
}
index = ["A", "B", "C"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

  01/01/2024       02/01/2024        
           a  b  c          a   b   c
A          1  4  7         10  13  16
B          2  5  8         11  14  17
C          3  6  9         12  15  18

Use stack, then reset the index and sort the values in the desired order:
df = df.stack(level=0).reset_index(names=["ID", "date"]).sort_values(["date", "ID"])

  ID        date   a   b   c
0  A  01/01/2024   1   4   7
2  B  01/01/2024   2   5   8
4  C  01/01/2024   3   6   9
1  A  02/01/2024  10  13  16
3  B  02/01/2024  11  14  17
5  C  02/01/2024  12  15  18

